# Extending a homeomorphism on the boundary to the interior

Tags: general-topology

Say we have two compact Hausdorff spaces $X,Y$ with open subsets $A \subset X, B \subset Y$ such that both are homeomorphic to the open unit disc and their boundaries $\partial A,\partial B$ are homeomorphic to the unit circle. If there is some given homeomorphism $h: \partial A \to \partial B$, can this be extended to a homeomorphism $\bar{h}: \bar{A} \to \bar{B}$?

This fact seems intuitively clear but I can't seem to find a good argument.

Comment: A closed disk without a point in the interior is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times [0,1)$. Use this.

Comment: (1) A and B are homeomorphic to the open unit disc and hence have no boundary. (2) There are pairs of compact, nonhomeomorphic spaces that both contain dense open disks. For example the closed disk and 2-sphere is such a pair.

Comment: @jspecter ; In my question, $A,B$ are open sets contained in larger spaces such that they do have boundaries in these spaces. Does that resolve the problem?

Comment: @Maanroof. Give an example.

Comment: @PVAL ; Thanks for the hint. It seems like something that should work but I'm not quit there yet.

Comment: @jspecter ; suppose $X,Y$ are two Riemann spheres and $A \subset X$ is an open neighborhood of $0 \in X$, homeomorphic to an open disc with boundary homeomorphic to $S^1$. The same for $B \subset Y$ but for example around $\infty \in Y$.

Comment: Great. It seems I was confused about the meaning of boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let A and B be open discs. Let X be the usual compactification of A (i.e. closed disc) but construct Y by taking the usual compactification of B and identifying opposite points of the boundary. Both remainders are circles but X and Y are not homeomorphic.

Comment: What if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth oriented compact two-dimensional manifolds?

Answer (score 0):

Given a homeomorphism $S^1\to S^1,\;\theta\mapsto\varphi(\theta)$, one can define a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $$re^{i\theta}\mapsto re^{i\varphi(\theta)},\;0\mapsto0.$$